# Freeradius authentication failed for unknown reason

Tags: centos, authentication, radius, freeradius, freeradius2

I followed [this instruction](http://ip6.com/projects/?p=336) to force freeradius to use mysql database.

and run freeradius in debug mod.
but it rejects all authentication.

mysql database :

```
mysql> select * from radcheck;
+----+----------+-----------+----+---------+
| id | username | attribute | op | value   |
+----+----------+-----------+----+---------+
|  1 | test     | Password  | == | test123 | 
|  2 | test     | Auth-Type | == | Local   | 
+----+----------+-----------+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

radtest command :

```
# radtest test test123 localhost 0 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 235 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
    User-Name = "test"
    User-Password = "test123"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.0.1
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=235, length=20
```

radiusd debug mod log:

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 51034, id=235, length=74
    User-Name = "test"
    User-Password = "test123"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.0.1
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0xbf111cbbae24fb0f0a558bfa26f53476
# Executing section authorize from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group authorize {...}
++[preprocess] returns ok
++[chap] returns noop
++[mschap] returns noop
++[digest] returns noop
[suffix] No '@' in User-Name = "test", looking up realm NULL
[suffix] No such realm "NULL"
++[suffix] returns noop
[eap] No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
++[eap] returns noop
++[files] returns noop
++[expiration] returns noop
++[logintime] returns noop
[pap] WARNING! No "known good" password found for the user.  Authentication may fail because of this.
++[pap] returns noop
ERROR: No authenticate method (Auth-Type) found for the request: Rejecting the user
Failed to authenticate the user.
Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
# Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group REJECT {...}
[attr_filter.access_reject]     expand: %{User-Name} -> test
attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
++[attr_filter.access_reject] returns updated
Delaying reject of request 20 for 1 seconds
Going to the next request
Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Sending delayed reject for request 20
Sending Access-Reject of id 235 to 127.0.0.1 port 51034
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
Cleaning up request 20 ID 235 with timestamp +4325
Ready to process requests.
```

where is the problem and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I've always seen the `Cleartext-Password` attribute set, not `Password`, and using the `:=` operator, not `==`. Also, I believe that setting `Auth-Type` is almost always wrong, so I suggest that you remove that. Try the following in the database table:

```
username="test", attribute="Cleartext-Password", op=":=", value="test123"
```

Comment: I did it ,but it will return following error again:

radtest test test123 localhost 0 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 40 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = "test"
User-Password = "test123"
NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.0.1
NAS-Port = 0
Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=40, length=20

Answer (score 2):

Might be a stupid question but have you uncommented the line

```
$INCLUDE  sql.conf
```

?

Comment: yes,I uncommented this line.